# reload UITableView issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have an application that follows MVC Design Pattern and I'm using " Singleton ".

- PlannerModel - The Model Class
- PlannerViewController - The Controller Class

PlannerViewController contains UITableView as an IBOutlet (The Delegate and the DataSource are connected to the files owner)

I'm trying to reload the table view from the Model class after finishing some data issues but the tableview doesn't respond (also I've notice that numberOfRowsInSection doesn't called)

I've tried couple of ways but with no result

First Attempt - the traditional method

```
[[[PlannerViewController sharedPlannerViewController]ItemsTableView]reloadData];
```

Second Attempt - Threads issue

```
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(reloadMealsTableView) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];

- (void)reloadMealsTableView{
    [[[PlannerViewController sharedPlannerViewController]mealItemsTableView]reloadData];
}
```

Third Attempt - casting issue !

```
[(UITableView *)[[PlannerViewController sharedPlannerViewController]mealItemsTableView] reloadData];
```

Forth Attempt - strange Way !!

```
[(UITableView *)[[[PlannerViewController sharedPlannerViewController]view]viewWithTag:9]reloadData];
```

Comment: From where did you called reloadData method? Is it from PlannerViewCOntroller or some other class?

Comment: u can use delegate pattern

Comment: make sure that you don't send `reloadData` message to `nil`. then make sure that the data was really changed.

Comment: Also, rather than having the model directly call the view controller, you should have it send a notification that it updated its data, and the view controller should simply listen for that notification. That way, other objects could listen for the notification if they need to, and you wouldn't have to change either your model or your view controller to make it work.

Comment: You're seriously breaking MVC 'boundaries'. Your Model should have no knowledge of the Controller, let alone the View. Never do UI stuff from within the Model...